# Unwantedborder when using images as radiobuttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some trouble when using images as Radiobuttons. When the radiobutton gets checked it also appear a border in top and left of the button. I only want the picture to change when checked, no other raised or sunken effect on the button. Does anyone know how this can be done? 
I use two images,one for checked and one other image for unchecked.
tkinter is the GUI framework I am using, sorry for not getting this info in the first post

```
R2 = Radiobutton(root, image = unChecked, selectimage = Checked, indicatoron=0,     borderwidth=0, variable=var, value="sparse",
              command=sel)
```

Comment: Can you post a bit more code? esp. where unChecked is declared.

Answer (score 0):

Radiobuttons (and any other widget that takes user input) has a "highlight border" that supports accessibility - it lets you know which widget accepts keyboard focus.

You can control this border with `highlightthickness`, `highlightbackground`, and `highlightcolor`. To turn off the border completely, set `highlightthickness` to 0 (zero).